# Get posts from the Main site to sub site - Wordpress MultiSites Network

Tags: wp-query, multisite

I'm trying to get posts from the main site to sub site using a query but It didn't work

**SITES :** 
MAIN SITE ID#1
- Post1
- Post 2

SUBSITE ID#2
I need to get the Above posts here - Post1 and Post2

Comment: you can use that : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_post

Comment: Can display all the posts of the main blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this codes to loop over the posts in the Main site:

```
<?php
$sites = wp_get_sites();
foreach($sites as $site) :
    // Only subsites
        // Connect to new multisite
        switch_to_blog($site['blog_id']);
        $case_args = array(
            'post_type'        => 'downloads',
            'posts_per_page'   => 1,
            'orderby'          => 'date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            );
        $latest_cases = new WP_Query($case_args);
        if ( $latest_cases->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();
// Quit multisite connection
restore_current_blog();
endforeach; 
?>
```